# VM - Append free space to Root partition

Tags: debian, virtual, disk, partition

do you please idea how can I append new free space for virtual Debian running on VM VirtualBox? 
I have made my virtual HDD bigger but free space is not alocated next to boot partition where I have root folder. I cannot use any live partition disk as this is just virtual OS, right? Do you have any clues how to add some space to pripary dev/sda1 partition?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N11rP.png)

Thakns!

Answer (score 0):

DONE -

1. I downloaded live cd of Gpart and mounted in VM VirtualBox manager
2. live version started (not debian) - I have deleted SWAP between Root SDA and free space, extended space on disk and created new SWAP

Sorry for spam